# rechts neben vs. rechts von

Tags: preposition

Ich frage mich, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen den zwei Sätzen gibt. Sind beide Formulierungen korrekt?

1. Stell den Schrank rechts neben den Kühlschrank.
2. Stell den Schrank rechts vom Kühlschrank.

Answer (score 4):

Das Verb *stellen* erwartet keinen Ort, sondern eine **Richtung**.

> Stell den Schrank rechts neben den Kühlschrank.

Das Adverbial *(rechts) neben+Akkusativ* bezeichnet eine Richtung. Zum Vergleich, folgendes ist falsch:

> <strike>Stell den Schrank rechts neben dem Kühlschrank.</strike>

Und zwar, weil das Adverbial *(rechts) neben+Dativ* einen Ort bezeichnet. Und genauso ist es mit

> <strike>Stell den Schrank rechts vom Kühlschrank.</strike>

Auch das Adverbial *(rechts) vom Kühlschrank* bezeichnet einen Ort. Man kann das übrigens heilen, indem man stattdessen das Verb *hinstellen* verwendet. Denn dieses Verb erwartet einen Ort, keine Richtung.

> Stell den Schrank rechts neben dem Kühlschrank hin.

> Stell den Schrank rechts vom Kühlschrank hin.

Answer (score 2):

Ich verstehe zwar beide, aber das zweite klingt merkwürdig.

Ich denke nicht, dass man "links/rechts von" sagen kann, wenn es (wie hier) um eine Richtung geht. Man kann sagen "der Schrank steht rechts neben dem Kühlschrank" oder "der Schrank steht rechts vom Kühlschrank", das bedeutet dasselbe, aber wenn es um eine Richtungs- und keine Ortsangabe geht, klingt "rechts von" sehr merkwürdig.